# what is the best practice for handling asynchronous api call that take time

Tags: asynchronous, design-patterns, microservices

So suppose I have an API to create a cloud instance asynchronously. So after I made an API call it will just return the success response, but the cloud instance will not been initialized yet. It will take 1-2 minutes to create cloud instance and after that it will save the cloud instance information (ex. ip, hostname, os) to db which mean I have to wait 1-2 minutes so I can fetch the data again to show cloud information. At first I try making a loading component, but the problem is that I don't know when the cloud instance is initialized (each instance has different time duration for creating). I'm considering using websocket or using *cron* or should I redesign my API? Has anyone design asynchronous system before how do you handle such a case.

Answer (score 1):

If the API that you call gives you no information on when it's done with its asynchronous processing, it seems to me that you'll have to check at intervals until you find that the resource is ready; i.e. to poll it.

This seems to me to roughly fit the description and intent of the [Polling Consumer pattern](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/PollingConsumer.html). In general, for asynchronous systems design, I can't recommend *Enterprise Integration Patterns* enough.

Answer (score 1):

As other noted you can either have a notification channel using WebSockets or poll the backend. Personally I'd probably go with the latter for this case and would actually create several APIs, one for initiating the work and get back a URL with "job id" in it where the status of the job can be polled.

RESTfully that would look something like `POST /instances` to initiate a job `GET /instances` see all the instances that are running/created/stopped and `GET /instances/<id>` to see the status of a current instance (initiating , failed , running or whatever)

Answer (score 0):

WebSockets would work, but might be an overkill for this use case. I would probably display a status of 'creating' or something similar after receiving the success response from the API call, and then start polling the API to see if the creation process has finished.